# Can a universal and existential quantifier for a constructor be commuted in pattern matching?

Tags: haskell

Here is a snippet that I think makes (type) sense, but which ghc doesn't like.
I was hoping that some tricky use of type annotations could make it work, but my experiments have failed.
Any suggestions?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Ex where

data T a where
  T :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> T a

foo :: (forall a . T a) -> Bool
foo (T f) = bar f

bar :: Functor f => (forall a . f a -> a) -> Bool
bar _f = True
```

It could very well be impossible since it amounts to commuting a universal and existential quantifier, but I was hoping.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. Consider `ex :: forall a . T a ; ex = T getConst`. Here `f ~ Const a` depends on `a`, while to call `bar` in your code you need to choose a single functor `f` and then pass `forall b . f b -> b`. The latter looks like `forall b . Const a b -> b` which is impossible to implement (without bottoms). Indeed, you are trying to convert forall-exists to exists-forall (and to do so without even introducing a choice function). I don't have a "great" counterexample for your specific case, but it looks impossible.

Comment: I guess you want something more general than what you wrote. As written, it looks like `bar` has no way to produce a `f t` value to pass to the argument function, or to `fmap`, so it must be a constant by parametricity (?) Can you elaborate?

Comment: `T a` contains a function for extracting an `a` from `f a` for some `f` or other. Without knowing what `f` is, we really can't provide a non-bottom argument to that function. So `T` seems fundamentally useless.

Comment: This is not meant to be a useful example, just a minimal one.

Answer (score 2):

I tried that example in Agda,
to see if it makes sense

```
module Comm where

open import Data.Bool using (Bool; true)

record T (A : Set) : Set₁ where
  constructor MkT
  field
    F : Set → Set
    f : F A → A

bar : {F : Set → Set} → (∀ A → F A → A) → Bool
bar _ = true

foo : (∀ A → T A) → Bool
foo k = bar {F = k Bool .T.F} λ A → {!k A .T.f!}
-- Goal: k Bool .T.F A → A
-- Have: T.F. (k A) A → A
```

In foo, we need to instantiate `forall a. T a` with some type.
As the type is parametric, any should do, and `F` would be the same.
But neither Agda nor Haskell have that parametricity built in.

So I think that with right use of `unsafeCoerce`,
things will work.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
module Ex where

import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty (..))
import GHC.Exts (Any)

data T a where
  T :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> T a

bar :: Functor f => (forall a . f a -> a) -> Bool
bar _f = _f `seq` True

foo :: (forall a . T a) -> Bool
foo t = foo' t t

foo' :: (forall a. T a) -> T Any -> Bool
foo' t (T f) = aux f where
    aux :: forall f. Functor f => (f Any -> Any) -> Bool
    aux f' = bar f''
      where
        f'' :: forall a. f a -> a
        f'' = unsafeCoerce f'

--- test

ex :: forall a. T a
ex = T (\(x :| _) -> x)

ex2 :: Bool
ex2 = foo ex
```

Comment: I disagree with "`F` would be the same". See my comment above.

Comment: @chi `forall a. T a` makes the `F` `forall a. Const a`. These, are all the same. With GADTs you can break it, but GADTs aren't (lawful) `Functor`s.